# Forgot laptop's entry level password

Tags: password, laptop

I have forgot laptop's entry level password which popups at the start....(don't know the exact terms)...

I need the data which is in the laptop's hard disk...Also, the DVD drive is not working....

Anybody has any idea of how I can access that data?

Comment: Which password do you mean? The one that it asks for *right after* switching on, or the one to log onto the operating system (i.e. Windows PW, Linux PW etc.).

Comment: @sleske: yes, the former one

Comment: We need to know what model of laptop it is, and also if the page that is asking for the password has any wording on it. It could be a BIOS password, or it could be something like a pointsec encryption password.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is commonly called the *BIOS password* (unless you mean the password to log on to the OS).

There are some ways to reset it, but most require HW modifications. Also, some models have a default PW that always works. For that, google your model and "bios password", as it's model-specific.

Another option is to just take out the HDD and put it into another computer or external enclosure. Then you should be able to read it (unless it uses HW level encryption, which is uncommon).

Comment: This password could also be for some encryption software, such as PointSec, which if this is the case, taking the hardrive out will not make it readable. If this is a laptop from a larger company, it's quite likely it will be encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

You mean the local password? If it can boot from USB stick or USB CD, boot with a Linux boot disc and run chntpw on the system to erase the local administrative user's password. You can get some information on it [here](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/).

Google around for bootable linux disc and chntpw and you should find some possible bootable distro's with the utility to use.

Answer (score 0):

I think he is referring to a pre-boot authentication password.  There are 'hacks' around this, but usually moving the HD to an external enclosure will not work.  The last time I had a staff member with this problem we ended up contacting the laptop manufacturer.

Good luck.

Comment: You are scaring me !!

Comment: It scared me too.  I think this type of authentication is on a lot of Dell laptops.  I havent seen it on many others.  There is rumor of a master password, but I didnt have any luck Googling for it.  I thought I was close a few times, but it never panned out.

Comment: Pre-boot authentication, as in the BIOS? Newer laptops are doing something to the hard disk that if you set the BIOS password the hard drive won't be readable even if you remove the disk and put it into an enclosure or other laptop?

Comment: it actually affects the drive itself, but is usually not enabled by default. On my Latitude E6500 the software is from a third-party called Embassy Software.  I do not trust it, so I dont use it, but some of my colleagues use it along with password/fingerprint scanner/smartcard and havent had any problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

if its a cmost password [this might help](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/CmosPwd)